# How to send external emails via Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix

Hello I installed a postfix MTA on a VPS with a domain linked to it.
The email forwarder (via aliases) and various mail-man mailing lists run on the server for Postfix.
The outgoing emails are also signed for Dkim via opedkim and DMARC is activated
This works correctly and https://www.mail-tester.com/ shows a 10 when I send an email via the command line.
So far so good.

Now I want to send an email from home with user@domain.nl
At the moment this goes through the service provider (xs4all) and often the email does arrive. However, a test via the above site gives a bad score.

My question: What is the minimum requirement to have the email @ home (via email client) sent via the VPS?
So I am only looking for sending via and not a complete server with mailboxes, databases etc.
Just say half an imap server (send only) Peter

Comment: Why do you not send the email directly to your server? There is no reason to send it to your ISP.

Comment: Thats exact the idea. But what are the requirements at the server side that it will accept email from a client?

Comment: You enabled submission in master.cf

Answer (score 0):

Minimum requirements of MTA connecting to other MTAs are:

1. Your MTA use HELO with a correct server name.
2. Your server name resolved into source IP address.
3. Source IP is resolved into that name.
4. If domain have SPF records - IP address should be allowed to send mail from this domain.

Also, not required but strictly needed is not having that IP in spam databases.